# Can we map textures in MTL file to an OBJ Model using SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, 3d-rendering

I'm trying to load OBJ model with MTL formatted textures. Here I am able to map textures using JPG files but not with MTL.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.